# Reference for Langlands dual homomorphisms

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, langlands-conjectures

I am looking for a reference that explains in detail the existence of Langlands dual homomorphisms. It seems that in the literature two references are given most often. The first is Borel's article *Automorphic $L$-functions* in the Corvallis proceedings. The relevant sections are 1.4, 2.1, and 2.5, and these refer to 2.11 in Springer's article *Reductive groups* in the same proceedings. The second reference one finds is 1.8 in Kottwitz's article *Stable trace formula: cuspidal tempered terms*. However, both of these references are quite terse.

Let $k$ be a field and let $\eta:G\to G'$ be a homomorphism of connected reductive groups over $k$. Assume that $\eta(G)$ is normal in $G'$. (Kottwitz also assumes that $\eta:G\to\eta(G)$ is separable, but Borel and Springer do not assume this. Is it necessary?) The following are the main claims needed. It would be great if there is a reference that explains them in more detail.

1. $\eta$ determines a morphism $\Psi_0(\eta):\Psi_0(G)\to\Psi_0(G')$ of the based root data. The notion of morphism is defined implicitly in 2.11 of Springer's article.
2. The morphism $\Psi_0(\eta)$ is $\Gamma_{\overline{k}/k}$-equivariant. (Borel 2.5.)
3. The dual morphism $\widehat{\Psi_0(\eta)}:\Psi_0(\hat{G'})\to\Psi_0(\hat{G})$ comes from a normal homomorphism $\hat{\eta}:\hat{G'}\to \hat{G}$. The homomorphism $\hat{\eta}$ is uniquely determined if it is required to be compatible with choices of pinnings for $\hat{G'}$ and $\hat{G}$. Changing the pinnings replaces $\hat{\eta}$ by a $\hat{G}^{\Gamma_{\overline{k}/k}}$-conjugate. (See Kottwitz 1.8.)
4. Once one fixes pinnings for $\hat{G'}$ and $\hat{G}$, the uniquely determined $\hat{\eta}$ is equivariant with the resulting actions of $\Gamma_{\overline{k}/k}$. (See Borel 2.5.)
5. One gets a unique $\hat{G}$-conjugacy class of L-homomorphisms ${}^L\eta:{}^LG'\to{}^LG$.

The parts that I would like most to get a better understanding of are 1 and the existence of $\hat{\eta}$. At the beginning of Section 5 of Steinberg's 1999 article, *The Isomorphism and Isogeny Theorems for Reductive Algebraic Groups*, he states that the isogeny theorem can be extended to arbitrary surjective homomorphisms. This covers the existence of $\hat{\eta}$ when $\eta$ is an embedding. However, this paper came after the articles by Borel and Kottwitz, so presumably they had something else in mind.

Answer (score 4):

We have that $G'$ is an almost-direct product of $\eta(G)$ and the almost-direct product of the duals of the simple factors of $G'$ not contained in $\eta(G)$, which allows us to reduce (1) and (3) to the case where $\eta$ is surjective.

I think you probably want to assume that $\eta$ is a quotient by a smooth, connected, normal subgroup followed by a central isogeny; this is automatic if $\eta$ is separable.  If you do not want to reduce to this case, then you have to handle something like the exceptional isogeny $\operatorname{SO}_{2n + 1, k} \to \operatorname{Sp}_{2n, k}$ when $\operatorname{char} k$ is $2$, whose dual homomorphism I guess should be a map $\operatorname{SO}_{2n + 1, \mathbb C} \to \operatorname{Sp}_{2n, \mathbb C}$; but I think that there are no non-trivial such homomorphisms.

When $\eta$ is a quotient by a smooth, connected, normal subgroup $N$ of $G$, we have a similar decomposition of $G$ as the almost-direct product of $N$ with a canonical complement.  Thus, if it is OK to make the reduction above, then we need only handle the case where $\eta$ is an isogeny.

In this case, if $(B, T, \mathcal X)$ is a pinning of $G_{\overline k}$, then $(B', T', \mathcal X') \mathrel{:=} (\eta_{\overline k}(B), \eta_{\overline k}(T), \eta_{\overline k}(\mathcal X))$ is a pinning of $G'_{\overline k}$.  We compute $\Psi_0(G_{\overline k})$ and $\Psi_0(G'_{\overline k})$ in terms of these pinnings, and then let $\Psi_0(\eta)$ be the obvious map.  If I understand correctly how $\Gamma_{\overline k/k}$ acts, then this is $\Gamma_{\overline k/k}$-equivariant: if we choose $\sigma \in \Gamma_{\overline k/k}$ and let $g \in G(\overline k)$ be such that $\sigma(B, T, \mathcal X)$ equals $\DeclareMathOperator\Ad{Ad}(g B g^{-1}, g T g^{-1}, \Ad(g)\mathcal X)$, then $\sigma(B', T', \mathcal X') = (\eta_{\overline k}(\sigma B), \eta_{\overline k}(\sigma T), \eta_{\overline k}(\sigma\mathcal X))$ equals $(g'B'g^{\prime\,{-1}}, g'T'g^{\prime\,{-1}}, \Ad(g')\mathcal X')$, where $g'$ equals $\eta_{\overline k}(g)$.
Then $\sigma$, viewed as a morphism $X_*(T) \to X_*(T)$, respectively $X_*(T') \to X_*(T')$, sends $\lambda$, respectively $\lambda'$, to $\DeclareMathOperator\Int{Int}\Int(g)^{-1} \circ \sigma \circ \lambda \circ \sigma^{-1}$, respectively $\Int(g')^{-1} \circ \sigma \circ \lambda \circ \sigma^{-1}$;
and then $\Psi_0(\eta)(\sigma\lambda) = \eta \circ \Int(g)^{-1} \circ \sigma \circ \lambda \circ \sigma^{-1}$ equals $\Int(g')^{-1} \circ \sigma \circ \eta \circ \lambda \circ \sigma^{-1} = \sigma(\Psi_0(\eta)(\lambda))$.

Still in the case where $\eta$ is a central isogeny, we have that $\widehat{\Psi_0(\eta)}$ is also a $\Gamma_{\overline k/k}$-equivariant, separable isogeny of root data, so that it is dual to a (necessarily central) $\Gamma_{\overline k/k}$-equivariant isogeny $\hat\eta : \hat{G'} \to \hat G$, as you say uniquely determined by choices of $\Gamma_{\overline k/k}$-fixed pinnings.  Since two different pinnings of $\hat{G'}$ are uniquely $\hat{G'}/\operatorname Z(\hat{G'})$-conjugate, the corresponding $\Gamma_{\overline k/k}$-equivariant homomorphisms are $(\hat{G'}/\operatorname Z(\hat{G'}))^{\Gamma_{\overline k/k}}$-conjugate; but it is not clear to me why the conjugacy can be lifted to $\smash{\hat{G'}}^{\Gamma_{\overline k/k}}$.  If $\operatorname Z(\hat{G'})$ is connected (equivalently, if the derived group of $G'$ is simply connected), then one can probably show that $H^1(\Gamma_{\overline k/k}, \operatorname Z(\hat{G'}))$ is trivial and deduce a suitable lifting; but I don't know about the case of disconnected dual centre.

Comment: I phrased my determination of $g$ in terms of $\sigma$ using a pinning, not just a Borel–torus pair, because I had pinned automorphisms on the mind; but, as @MikhailBorovoi [points out](https://mathoverflow.net/a/466613), this isn't really necessary for dealing with based root data.  Using a pinning determines $g$ up to translation by the centre, i.e., determines the resulting inner automorphism, whereas using a Borel–torus pair determines $g$ only up to translation by the torus; but that's OK because the torus acts trivially on the associated based root datum.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\BRD}{\Psi_0}
\newcommand{\X}{{\sf X}}
\newcommand{\isoto}{\overset\sim\longrightarrow}
$Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

Let $G$ be a (connected) reductive group over an algebraically closed field $k$.
Let $T\subset G$ be a maximal torus, and $B\supset T$ be a Borel subgroup of $G$, containing $T$.
We say that $(T,B)$ is a *Borel pair* in $G$.
We denote:

$X=\X^*(T)$, $X^\vee=\X_*(T)$ (the character and cocharacter groups of $T$;

$R=R(G,T)\subset X$, $\ R^\vee=R^\vee(G,T)\subset X^\vee$ the root system and the coroot system;

$S=S(G,T,B)\subset R$, $\ S^\vee=S^\vee(G,T,B)\subset R^\vee$ the set of simple roots and the set of simple coroots.

We write
\begin{align*}
&\BRD(G,T,B)=(X,X^\vee, R,R^\vee,S, S^\vee),\\
& \BRD^\vee(G,T,B)=(X^\vee,X, R^\vee, R, S^\vee,S)
\end{align*}
for the corresponding based root data.

If $(T',B')$ is another Borel pair, then there exists $g\in G(k)$ such that
$$ gTg^{-1}=T',\quad\ gBg^{-1}=B'.$$
Moreover, if $g_+\in G(k)$ is another such element, then $g_+=gt$ for some $t\in T(k)$.
We see that the isomorphism
$${\rm inn}(g)\colon (G,T,B)\isoto (G,T',B')$$
induces an isomorphism
$$g^*\colon \BRD(G',T',B')\isoto  \BRD(G,T,B),$$
which  *does not depend on the choice of* $g$.
Thus we can identify the based root data $\BRD(G,T,B)$ for all Borel pairs $(T,B)$
and obtain the *canonical based root datum* $\BRD(G)$.

The group of semi-linear automorphisms of $G$ acts on $\BRD(G)$;
see, for instance, section 3.2 of [Borovoi, Kunyavskii, Lemire, Reichstein, Stably Cayley groups in characteristic zero](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.1329).
In particular, if $G$ is defined over a field $K$, not necessarily algebraically closed, then the Galois group acts on $\BRD(G_{\overline K})$.

Now let $\eta\colon G_1\to G_2$ be a central isogeny.
Let $(T_1,B_1)$ be a Borel pair in $G_1$.
Set  $(T_2,B_2)=\eta_*(T_1,B_1)$.
Write
\begin{align*}
&\BRD(G_1,T_1,B_1)=(X_1,X_1^\vee, R_1,R_1^\vee,S_1, S_1^\vee),\\
&\BRD(G_2,T_2,B_2)=(X_2,X_2^\vee, R_2,R_2^\vee,S_2, S_2^\vee).
\end{align*}
We obtain a  homomorphism
$$\eta^*\colon X_2\to X_1,\quad\   \chi_2\mapsto \chi_2\circ\eta\quad \ \text{for}\ \, \chi_2\in X_2=\X^*(T_2)$$
sending $R_2$ to $R_1$ and sending $S_2$ to $S_1$,
and we obtain a homomorphism
$$\eta_*\colon X_1^\vee\to X_2^\vee,\quad \  \nu_1\mapsto \eta\circ \nu_1\quad \ \text{for}\ \, \nu_1\in X_1^\vee=\X_*(T_1)$$
sending $R_1^\vee$ to $R_2^\vee$ and sending $S_1^\vee$ to $S_2^\vee$.
Thus we obtain an induced morphism
$$\eta_{\scriptscriptstyle{\BRD}}\colon \BRD^\vee(G_1)\to \BRD^\vee(G_2).$$

I hope this helps!